# Subset data by condition

Tags: r

If I have data look like this:

```
A  B    C
1  GM1  100
2  DOX  10
3  GM2  3
4  GM3  99
5  MY   62
6  GMPN 30
```

How could I using R let data looks like:(only choose include "GM" data)

```
A  B    C
1  GM1  100
3  GM2  3
4  GM3  99
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grep`

```
 df1[grep('GM\\d+', df1$B),]
 #  A   B   C
 #1 1 GM1 100
 #3 3 GM2   3
 #4 4 GM3  99
```

Or as @ColonelBeauvel mentioned

```
 subset(df1, grepl('GM\\d+', B))
```

Comment: or `subset(df, grepl('GM', B))` may be even neater.

Comment: Thanks, one problem with `subset` is it is a bit slow, but on the otherhand, it is good in preserving the data.frame structure when there is a single column

Comment: I don't think that `subset` is *that* slow. Did anyone ever test it?

Comment: If I have data #06 looks like:

`6  GMPY  30`

But I don't want GMPY, How could i do?

Comment: @JefferyChen In that case, we have to change the pattern to `subset(df, grepl('GM\\d+', B))`